# :not selector with <a> in <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `a` in a `div` and want to change the window location on click of `div`.

```
<div class="div-class">
  <a href="/" target="_blank" class="a-class"></a>
  <a href="/somewhere" target="_blank" class="a-class-2"></a>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".div-class:not(.a-class, .a-class-2)", function() {
   window.location = "/somewhere-else";
}
```

When clicking on either a, a new tab opens and the current window changes location. I want it to be that if you click on any a it will open a new tab, if you click on the containing div it will change window location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can hook to the `a` elements directly and call `stopPropagation()` on the event passed to the handler. This will stop the event bubbling to the `div` and will ensure only the new tab is opened.

Similarly, you can hook to the `click` event of the `div` element to call `window.location.assign()` to change the page URL. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".a-class, .a-class-2", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('a clicked');
}).on('click', '.div-class', function() {
  console.log('div clicked');
  // location.assign("/somewhere-else"); // commented out to stop breaking the snippet
});
```

```css
/* this is only to make the hit areas more obvious in the snippet */
a { border: 1px solid #C00; }
div { border: 1px solid #0C0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class">
  <a href="/" target="_blank" class="a-class">a-class</a>
  <a href="/somewhere" target="_blank" class="a-class-2">a-class-2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rory's answer works, but I don't think it needs two handlers or to call `stopPropagation` ([which can be harmful](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)). You can filter on the event target using [`jQuery.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```js
$(document).on("click", ".div-class", function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is(".a-class, .a-class-2")) {
    console.log("going /somewhere-else");
  }
  // You could also do
  if( $(event.target).is(".div-class") ) {
    console.log("going /somewhere-else v2");      
  }
});
```

```css
a { background-color: #eee; }
div { border: 1px solid #0C0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class">
  <a href="/" target="_blank" class="a-class">link 1</a>
  <a href="/somewhere" target="_blank" class="a-class-2">link 2</a>
</div>
```